# Type mismatch: inferred type is <no name provided> but Callback<Post!>! was expected

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have the function

```
        val client = NetworkService()
        val call = client.getService().getAllPost()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Post>>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Post>>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Get post failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ArrayList<Post>>,
                response: Response<ArrayList<Post>>) {
                response.body()?.let{
                    post ->
                    adapter?.updateData(post)
                }?: kotlin.run {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Get post failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }

        })

    }
```

*and have the error *

`Type mismatch: inferred type is <no name provided> but Callback<Post!>! was expected`

in `call.enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Post>>`
Callback ArrayList dont wanna work with object, idk why

Pls help this it

Comment: Check your imports.

Comment: Check Your Model Class..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that you've imported a package with the same name as the one you actually meant to import.

Source: This just happened to me.  Sometimes I don't read the package names closely enough when IntelliJ auto-imports new classes.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have somewhere in your code:

```
fun call(@Body body: Any): Call<Post>
```

The value to return is not `Call<Post>` as described in your error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is  but Callback<Post!>! was expected

It is `Call<List<Post>>`:

```
fun call(@Body body: Any): Call<List<Post>>
```

(Note that I have put `Any` as the type of your argument because I don’t know its type.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether import package is from android or androidx

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the import is

```
import retrofit2.Callback
```

and not`import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback`

Answer (score -1):

Try to rebuild the project, works for me.